# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED AWS EC2 when performing GET to backend server

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

This is my first AWS deployment and I have what is going to be a simple question (but not for me). I would appreciate any help I can get.
I have a React frontend and a backend node server running on an AWS EC2 instance.  I have no problem serving the front end to my browser from port 80 (NGINX server) on the public IP address for the EC2 instance but the GET request to the node server on port 3001 returns an error to the console "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
Troubleshooting so far;

1. confirmed NGINX and Node servers are running on their proper ports
2. I performed a curl request from the EC2 terminal (curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/users) to the backend server and the information is served successfully from the server/DB but when the request comes from running the app in the client, the connection is refused.
3. I made many changes to the NGINX .conf file (one at a time) including using the public IP vs using localhost (or even 127.0.0.1:3001) for the backend express server but with no success.
4. Made sure to restart the NGINX server to pick up .conf changes.
5. Since I am able to get a response when I use a "curl" request from the VM terminal but not when I request from the client, I wonder if it has something to do with my security group rules.  I have Type "HTTPS" on port 443 and "HTTP" on port 80 with "0.0.0.0/0" and "::/0" on both and SSH on port 22 with "0.0.0.0/0".  Is there anything that I am missing?

Here is the NGINX .conf info for the servers

```
   server {
    listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

       location /{
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/aws-thought/client/build;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
}
```

Comment: You generally don't access the underlying port directly.  Nginx is acting as a proxy for the back end.  Port 3001 is very likely blocked by the security group inbound rules of the EC2.  Have you tried to just access the server API without the port number?  Based on what I'm seeing it should work.  Note that you need to setup SSL (port 443) for it to work - it will not work out of the box.  In that case, and for testing only, just use http.

Comment: I did drop the port from the path for location /api in the .conf file but it did not work.  I have updated the question to include more information including security group information.

Comment: I did figure out what was happening.  I changed from https to http in the API call from the front end and that resolved the problem.  I am puzzled why since I have both http and https specified in the security rules, but at the end of the day that did resolve the connection problem on the backend.